# is it possible to pass iostream into a function?

Tags: c++, function, parameters, iostream

What I mean:

Everyone knows this method of redirecting stream to output:

```
cout << "sometext"
```

but is it possible to pass that stream to a function like this:

```
my_function() << "sometext";
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? What you wrote calls my_function(), and performs the return value's operator<< with "sometext" - Assuming  operator<< is defined for the return value's type. Otherwise you'll get a compilation error.

Comment: You are not "redirecting" anything, and a string is not a stream. Don't confuse C++ with the shell. This is just a function call.

Comment: What do you mean with redirecting stream to output? Your example simply writes `"sometext"` to the outputstream `cout`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes*:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>

std::ostream & my_function() { return std::cout; }

// ...

my_function() << "Hello world.\n";
```

*) Nothing you said in words is entirely correct, and you may well struggle later integrate this into your project, but this answer shows how to make your code do what you want.

Comment: @MooingDuck: I propose we let the OP tell us her needs rather than attempting to second-guess!

Comment: I just wanted to pass a stream to a function and your example works, but I wonder how to output stream in function, because you can return only at the end. I try to do it by `std::cout << std::cout;` but I get : `0x6fcc92c4Hello world`, how to get rid of this memory address ?

Comment: @rsk82: I'm sorry, your question is really really unclear, and I simply cannot understand what you're trying to achieve. I sort of have an idea and I'm sure whatever you really want can be done easily, but I just cannot figure out what exactly you're after. Could you please rework your post to be more specific? Maybe include a more thorough example of what you want to happen (pseudocode is fine).

Answer (score 5):

> Everyone knows this method of redirecting stream to output:

That's not what that does. The stream is called `cout`; that's the iostream object. The `<<` operator does not redirect anything. The `std::ostream` objects all have overloaded `operator<<` functions. Those functions are invoked when you use `<<` with a stream on the left-hand side and some type that has an overload for it on the right.

`<< "sometext"` is not a "stream" that can be "redirected". It isn't even a valid expression in C++. The `<<` operator is binary. it takes two parameters.

`my_function() << "sometext";` can only work if it returns a `std::ostream` class or something derived from it. Or something that has an overloaded `operator<<` defined for it and `const char*`.

Answer (score 1):

```
cout << "sometext"
```

This is not "redirecting stream to output" it is invoking the `operator <<` function on the `cout` object with the string literal "sometext"

if `my_function()` is returning a `ostream` which has `operator <<` overloaded then `my_function() << "sometext"` will compile else it will give an error.

Comment: You can't really "return an `ostream`" on account of their a) being uninstantiable and b) being uncopyable.

Comment: You can return them by reference, just not by value.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a way to overload `<<` for your own function unrelated to streams, here is how you can do it:

```
struct MyStruct {
    void DoSomething(const string& s);
};

MyStruct &operator<<(MyStruct &x, const string& s) {
   x.DoSomething(s);
   return x;
}

MyStruct& my_function() {
    return MyStruct;
}

int main() {
    my_function() << "Hello, world!";
}
```

In this example, `DoSomething` will be called on the instance of `MyStruct` returned from `my_function`, and `"Hello, world!"` will be passed to it as an argument.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you are asking about, the closest equivalent of a shell redirect for a function that uses `std::cout` for output is probably to switch temporarily `std::cout`'s internal stream buffer for a different one.

Of course, this is inherently not thread safe and won't cope if the function itself expects `std::cout` and `stdout` to be the same underlying thing.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
    std::stringbuf redir( std::ios_base::out );
    std::streambuf* save = std::cout.rdbuf( &redir );

    my_function(); // cout output ends up in redir

    std::cout.rdbuf( save ); // restore original cout
}
```